# Unable to read some text values from webpage

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I encounter strange behaviour of selenium web browser where I read some data from table that's on webpage. Webpage is behind password, so I must input password and click on submit. After that I can read data from webpage where is table with rows and columns.

#### The problem

I have 8 columns and Selenium webdriver can successfully read 5 of them. The sixth columns is named status and even when I try only to get text from that column it returns "" and should return for example "Potvrzené" or "Nevyřízené".

```
string test = browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"post-580\"]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]")).Text;
```

But when I try to read for example column fifth with telefon (telephone number) it will return that text value. Could it be that selenium webbrowser doesn't support Czech chars?

#### My Code

```
        // Google setup
        var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.AddArguments("--headless");

        // Console hiding
        var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

        try
        {
            using (var browser = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions))
            {
                // Page setup 
                browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("my-page");

                // Password adding + clicking
                browser.FindElement(By.Id("pwbox-580")).SendKeys("password");
                browser.FindElement(By.Name("Submit")).Click();

                // Finging table
                IWebElement tableElement = browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"post-580\"]/div/div[2]/table"));

                // Finding row
                IList<IWebElement> rows = tableElement.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"post-580\"]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr"));


                // Data
                int pocet = 0;
                rezervace_data.Clear();

                foreach (IWebElement row in rows)
                {
                    // Row reading
                    IList<IWebElement> columns = row.FindElements(By.XPath(".//td"));

                    // Inicialization 
                    rezervace_data.Add(pocet, new Params_Rezervace());

                    // Storing data to dictionary
                    rezervace_data[pocet].Cas = columns[0].Text;
                    rezervace_data[pocet].Pocet_Hostu = columns[1].Text;
                    rezervace_data[pocet].Jmeno = columns[2].Text;
                    rezervace_data[pocet].Email = columns[3].Text;
                    rezervace_data[pocet].Telefon = columns[4].Text;
                    rezervace_data[pocet].Status = columns[5].Text;
                    rezervace_data[pocet].Podrobnosti = columns[6].Text;

                    if (columns[7].Text == "")
                    {
                        rezervace_data[pocet].Stul = "Preferují stůl uvnitř";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rezervace_data[pocet].Stul = "Preferují stůl venku";
                    }
                    


                    // Next row to dictionary
                    pocet++;
                }
                // Ending 
                browser.Close();
                browser.Quit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error getting data from website! \n" + ex, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

#### Some information

1. Selenium webbrowser version: 4.8.1
2. Webpage with Czech chars like (ěščřžýáíé)
3. Winfrom app with C#

[image]

Thanks for your help, maybe I am missing something, but I don't know what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things might possible,

1. Lazy page loading, you need to wait for element to be loaded.
   Use Selenium explicit wait or sleep after login successfully! and wait for table loaded successfully
2. May be some element is hidden on the page, or you need to scroll right of the page. You could try `GetAttribute("textContent")` instead `Text`

Instead of this

```
rezervace_data[pocet].Podrobnosti = columns[6].Text
```

Try this

```
rezervace_data[pocet].Podrobnosti = columns[6].GetAttribute("textContent")
```